# Changing android:layout_height and android:gravity in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, gravity

I'm new to android development and I've stumbled upon a problem I couldn't solve with the help of existing *StackOverflow* questions.

In the list of custom items I'm loading a *TextView* object which can use 2 different styles (both defined in *styles.xml*) - if there's a secondary *TextView* object, the style applied is *itemHeadingText_Medium*, and if not it's *itemHeadingText_Large*. I'm changing the style programmaticaly in the *ListItemAdapter* class.

```
<!-- Heading in each list item -->
<style name="itemHeadingText_Large" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>

    <!-- Testing height and gravity -->
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<!-- Heading in each list item -->
<style name="itemHeadingText_Medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Sadly, the *android:layout_height* and *android:gravity* aren't applied to the view, and whole app looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAqrl.jpg). Here's how both *TextViews* are defined:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondary"
            style="@style/itemSecondaryText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

I would like to center vertically the *Lorem Ipsum* heading of the second item provided in the screenshot.

**EDIT: 25 June 2017**

I managed to achieve what I wanted by changing the height programmatically using the *getLayoutParams().height* and adding the android:gravity attribute to the *TextView* xml definition - after all in both styles text can be centered vertically within its *TextView*.

Nevertheless, my question on how to do that in *styles.xml* is still open!

Comment: Can you please post the complete XML file code of this layout?

Comment: @ZohaibHassan Sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/y8nA2tbh

Comment: I'll check your code and get back to you soon.

Comment: In a meanwhile I achieved the desired effect by adding some java code into the project (25 June 2017's edit). I'm still curious how to do that in the xml file though!

Answer (score 0):

android:gravity will specify how the text should be laid out within the TextView, if the View is larger than the text

android:layout_gravity will specify how the View itself should be laid out in its ViewGroup.

I would try replacing gravity with layout_gravity

Comment: No change visible when using the layout_gravity. I'm using gravity here because my original idea was to make TextView bigger and then center the text within it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I can see in your code is:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary"
        style="@style/itemSecondaryText" // Look at this line
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

You are using "itemSecondaryText" style for your textview, but in your styles.xml there isn't any style named "itemSecondaryText". You have "itemHeadingText_Medium" and "itemHeadingText_Large" in your style.xml but there isn't item named "itemSecondaryText".

I guess this is the issue, otherwise everything looks good.

Comment: This is the other TextView, the one for secondary text ("Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Ipsum" in the screeshot I've provided) and it's working perfectly. Like I said I'm changing the style for the first TextView only programmatically. So this isn't the issue.

Comment: TextView which style is being changed is using the "heading" id.